# Ubuntu freezes and restarts

Tags: 16.04, hardware, freeze, restart

My system randomly freezes and reboots. Also it is true if try to boot ubuntu from flash drive and I tried to use different ubuntu versions like 14 or 16.10, currently using 16.04. Looks like a hardware problem. So I installed **mcelog** to catch this kind of errors. For previous reboots I get

```
TIME 1486052195 Thu Feb 2 18:16:35 2017
MCG status:
MCi status:
Uncorrected error
Error enabled
Processor context corrupt
MCA: Internal parity error
STATUS b200000000010005 MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP c0a APICID 6 SOCKETID 0 
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 94

mcelog: failed to prefill DIMM database from DMI data
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 0
CPU 3 BANK 0 
TIME 1486108417 Fri Feb 3 09:53:37 2017
MCG status:
MCi status:
Error overflow
Uncorrected error
Error enabled
Processor context corrupt
MCA: Internal parity error
STATUS f20000c000010005 MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP c0a APICID 6 SOCKETID 0 
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 94

mcelog: failed to prefill DIMM database from DMI data
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 0
CPU 3 BANK 0 
TIME 1486147573 Fri Feb 3 20:46:13 2017
MCG status:
MCi status:
Error overflow
Uncorrected error
Error enabled
```

Also I have Windows 10 installed on my machine and for windows there was no crashes
My machine:

- Motherboard: MSI H170A PC Mate (MS-7971)
- CPU: QuadCore Intel Core i7-6700, 3400 MHz (34 x 100)
- GPU: MSI GTX 970 (MS-V316)

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB and try running memtest

Comment: I've ran it for 6 hours and no errors